# How to prove one-to-one correspondence in vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-fields, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I am given a vector subspace $S$ over the space $\{0, 1\}^n$, and a vector space $S^{\perp}$ which contains the set of vectors in $\{0, 1\}^n$ which are perpendicular to all the vectors in $S$. I have to prove that is the a vector is a part of $\{0, 1\}^n$, either it belongs to $S^{\perp}$, or it is perpendicular to exactly half of the element in S.
I believe one way to solve it is to prove one-to-one correspondence between elements $\textbf{s}$ or $S$ which satisfy $\textbf{s}\cdot\textbf{z}=0$ and others which satisfy $\textbf{s}\cdot\textbf{z}=1$, for some $\textbf{z} \notin S^{\perp}$, but a member of $\{0, 1\}^n$.
But I am not sure on how to carry on this problem. I need some hint. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any small cases like $n=3$ or $n=4$?

Comment: I have but I am confused on how to prove it because $S$ is just a subset of $\{0, 1\}^n$. I have tried by considering both the subspaces $S$ and $S^{\perp}$. Plus I also have no idea how to generalize it. I tried but I don't know what I am doing.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. I guess $\{0,1\}$ is the field of two elements. Do we need to show the existence of such a vector $z$ that satisfies $|\{x:z\cdot x=0\}|=|\{x:z\cdot x=1\}|$?

Comment: So, $S$ is a subspace of field created by $\{0,1\}^n$ and so is $S^{\perp}$. Each elements of $S^{\perp}$ is perpendicular to all the elements of $S$. We need to show that if we have a vector $\textbf{z}$ in the field $\{0,1\}^n$, it either belongs to $S^{\perp}$ or is perpendicular to exactly half of the elements of $S$.

Comment: So, you're using universal quantifier. But what if e.g. $z\in S$? Btw, $\{0,1\}$ is the base field and $\{0,1\}^n$ is a vector space over that.